# Exporting/ETL data from Hive to MySQL

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie

I have a table in Hive called foo. I want to load data into MySQL table bar from Hive table foo. I want to do it using Sqoop Action - Oozie.

I am looking for an Oozie workflow.

--

My Hive table schema is:

```
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS foo (
id int, city string
)
row format delimited 
fields terminated by '\t'
lines terminated by '\n'
LOCATION
'/user/cloudera/foo' ;
```

--

My MySQL table schema is:

```
mysql> create table bar (id int, city varchar(25));
```

--

I loaded local file foo to Hive table foo:

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ cat foo
1   a
4   b
```

Content of file foo are tab separated.

```
hive> load data local inpath '/home/cloudera/foo' into table foo;
```

--

Sqoop command could be something like:

```
sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://ap1.abcxyz.net/test --username rio --password r3o% --table bar  --export-dir /user/cloudera/foo --input-fields-terminated-by '\t' --input-lines-terminated-by '\n'
```

--

Thanks,
Rio

Comment: Can you be more specific about the question? `I want to do it using Sqoop Action - Oozie.` is not a question

Comment: I am looking for a sqoop action as defined in link: http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_SqoopActionExtension.html

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with Oozie but I think that you have to define an `sqoop job` that exports the data from Hive and then define it in Oozie as an action

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://hadooped.blogspot.fr/2013/06/apache-sqoop-part-3-data-transfer.html)

Comment: Looking for someone to write the detail oozie